# Why flexbox in bootstrap isnt behaving as it should?

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I have to edit an already-made complex project(which is in PHP) using HTML, bootstrap, and CSS. The flexbox doesn't respond correctly. I need two cards in a row. I tried doing it in an empty file and it displays as it should, but when I paste it inside the project it shows them stacked on top of each other and stretched the whole device width.

the structure of two cards:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
  <div class="card costum-card mt-5">
    <div class="card-head mt-4 mx-3">
      <h1>Mix&Max</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card mt-2 mx-3 border border-white">
      <div class="card nested-card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="phone.png" class="img-fluid card-img" />
          <p class="card-body-bold">One Smart Pro</p>
          <p class="card-body-light">10 GB, Minuta, SMS Pa Limit</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card costum-card mt-5">
    <div class="card-head mt-4 mx-3">
      <h1>Mix&Max</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card mt-2 mx-3 border border-white">
      <div class="card nested-card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="phone.png" class="img-fluid card-img" />
          <p class="card-body-bold">One Smart Pro</p>
          <p class="card-body-light">10 GB, Minuta, SMS Pa Limit</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I'm not seeing ang columns in place though.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `.col-6` to each bootstrap column to specify that it should take half of the row width (which in 12).

**Try this:**

```
 <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
      <div class="card costum-card mt-5 col-6">
        <div class="card-head mt-4 mx-3">
          <h1>Mix&Max</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card mt-2 mx-3 border border-white">
          <div class="card nested-card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img src="phone.png" class="img-fluid card-img" />
              <p class="card-body-bold">One Smart Pro</p>
              <p class="card-body-light">10 GB, Minuta, SMS Pa Limit</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card costum-card mt-5 col-6">
        <div class="card-head mt-4 mx-3">
          <h1>Mix&Max</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card mt-2 mx-3 border border-white">
          <div class="card nested-card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img src="phone.png" class="img-fluid card-img" />
              <p class="card-body-bold">One Smart Pro</p>
              <p class="card-body-light">10 GB, Minuta, SMS Pa Limit</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```